# What happens to an obviously correct answer that is never marked (and no other answer is marked)?

Tags: discussion

Maybe the asker's computer has caught on fire and he couldn't return to mark an answer correct.  How would the answer ever be marked?

My example is this question: [What is the name of the movie where the president crash lands in a prison city?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3000/what-is-the-name-of-the-movie-where-the-president-crash-lands-in-a-prison-city/3001#3001)

One answer, seems to be right.  (I want my rep!)

Comment: Welcome to the stackexchange network.  Those are called "Drive By" questions.  The OP will most likely never be back.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Accepting an answer is more of a social convention than anything else.

It simply means the OP felt that particular answer met *their* needs better than other answers. Whether the community agrees with this or not, is completely unrelated -- though equally important.

It's also the source of things like the [Populist](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/badges/49/populist) badge.

Answer (score 7):

Nothing.  The asker needs to mark the correct answer.

Comment: Makes me want to create a feature request like if the asker isn't seen for a month after asking then the highest-ranked answer goes to mods for marking approval.

Comment: As the community grows and question volume increases, it becomes less of an issue, I think.

Comment: Given that answers are ranked by vote, it also doesn't matter.  Assuming that the most votes go to the answer that would be accepted, the ranking would be the same (if the best answer isn't the highest voted, publicise the question so that changes).  In terms of rep, 15 is less than 2 votes, so it's pretty insignificant.

Answer (score 4):

We need a big chalkboard in front of which [the user](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/1588/jonathan-mayhak) will be made to write, "I will not ever again stay off stack exchange for six days when I have a question open", over and over, until he breaks down sobbing.

Please check this off as the correct answer; I've got zero points coming to me when you do, damnit!

Comment: I sense some sarcasm but can't seem to find it.